# Serving Static content from Nginx but handling error pages in Django

Tags: django, nginx, http-status-code-404

My static and media files are served by Nginx and other requests are served by Django.

I have a custom 404 page which is served by Django. Since Nginx is handling static content any requests to /static/* which throws 404 is also handled by Nginx. I can set static custom 404 page in Nginx but I want Django to handle any 404.

Is it possible to serve static content from Nginx but in case of 404, the request get forwarded to Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have defined your django proxy pass

```
upstream django_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

Then you can do this

```
location /static/ {
     try_files $uri @django;
     ....
}
location @django { 
    proxy_pass django_server;
}
```

Comment: I use gunicorn for django container. Maybe because of this I had to write proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000 instead of django_server. proxy_pass to upstream server name threw 502 Bad Gateway error. I still do not understand why I had to write 0.0.0.0:8000 but its working.

Comment: yes, that sounds very strange to me as well but as long as it works, let's let it be :)